# Java program not running correctly on MAC

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, jframe

I have recently started using a mac to develop on and i am having a strange problem.

Take the Program below:

```
public class Driver {

    public static void main(String [ ] args) {
        SolarSystem SSpanel = new SolarSystem(600, 600);
        SSpanel.drawSolarObject(0, 0, 30, "YELLOW");
    }
}
```

the SolarSystem class extends JFrame and basically when the new SolarSystem is created it makes a panel of that size.

the drawSolarObjects basically draws a circle of a certain colour and size. finishedDrawing actually makes the object appear on the panel.

The example above does work but I have more complex requirements which involve putting this into a while loop.

this is where it gets weird, if i run the below program with cmd on a windows computer it works fine and prints the yellow circle to the screen. On my mac, adding this while loop causes it to just create the panel but not paint the yellow circle.

```
public class Driver{

    public static void main(String [ ] args) {
        boolean oMove = true;
        SolarSystem SSpanel = new SolarSystem(600, 600);
        while(oMove){
            SSpanel.drawSolarObject(0, 0, 30, "YELLOW");
            SSpanel.finishedDrawing();
        }
    }
}
```

I put a print into my loop to check it was running through it and that showed that it was definitely running through the loop.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Ive am adding the functions so you can get a better picture

SolarSystem Constructer:

```
public SolarSystem(int width, int height)
{
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;

    this.setTitle("The Solar System");
    this.setSize(width, height);
    this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);      
}
```

drawSolarObject Function:

```
public void drawSolarObject(double distance, double angle, double diameter, String col)
{
    Color colour = this.getColourFromString(col);
    double centreOfRotationX = ((double) width) / 2.0; 
    double centreOfRotationY = ((double) height) / 2.0; 

    double rads = Math.toRadians(angle);
    double x = (int) (centreOfRotationX + distance * Math.sin(rads)) - diameter / 2;
    double y = (int) (centreOfRotationY + distance * Math.cos(rads)) - diameter / 2;

    synchronized (this)
    {
        if (things.size() > 1000)
        {
            System.out.println("\n\n");
            System.out.println(" ********************************************************* ");
            System.out.println(" ***** Only 1000 Entities Supported per Solar System ***** ");
            System.out.println(" ********************************************************* ");
            System.out.println("\n\n");

            this.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
        }
        else
        {
            SolarObject t = new SolarObject((int)x, (int)y, (int)diameter, colour);
            things.add(t);
        }
    }
}
```

finishedDrawing function:

```
public void finishedDrawing()
{
    try
    {
        this.repaint();
        Thread.sleep(30);
    }
    catch (Exception e) { }

    synchronized (this)
    {
        things.clear();
    }
}
```

This all works fine on a windows PC

Answer (score 2):

Your code risks tying up the Swing event thread preventing it from drawing on your GUI, and effectively freezing your program. Instead use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), not a while loop to achieve your goal.

e.g.,

```
final SolarSystem SSpanel = new SolarSystem(600, 600);
int timerDelay = 100;
new Timer(timerDelay, new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // do repeated action in here
    }
}).start();
```

As an aside, I was going to place,

```
SSpanel.drawSolarObject(0, 0, 30, "YELLOW");
SSpanel.finishedDrawing();
```

inside my timer code, but it wouldn't make sense because this code isn't "dynamic" and doesn't change anything or do any animation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You made me think to check into the finishedDrawing() function (i did not write this function) and it does have a thread.sleep(30) in it. Might be a stupid question is not delaying it?

Comment: @user1680768: you should have no `Thread.sleep(...)` in your Swing code that might run on the Swing event thread. Instead and again, use a Swing Timer. If you didn't write this method, who did?

Comment: I'm learning java and this is a task base thing with classes already written and some documentation on how to use them. I had everything working fine on my windows computer which made me think the code wasn't the issue. I now unfortunately need to continue work on my mac and can't get it to work. I am trying to implement the swing timer with no luck so far. I have added more information to do with the functions. I appreciate the help.